# Traces left in OS after copying files between USB drives

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive

If I plug two USB flash drives into a networked computer running Windows XP and copy files from one to another, are there any traces left and can the specific files be traced? I dont want any of my personal files left on the networked computer.

Comment: Depends. How are you copying?

Comment: Copied by highlighting then right clicking copy then righting clicking paste.

Answer (score 0):

Once you restart Windows, you'll quickly overwrite anything in memory and you'll be okay.

Comment: ... No you won't. Windows doesn't deliberately flush memory.

Comment: "Flush" was probably the wrong word to use. It'll be overwritten, or highly unlikely of recovery.

Comment: If you're incredibly paranoid, consider turning the computer off and waiting for about 15 minutes. I remember something from the bygone ages where some kids found that RAM gradually removes data as it's powered down, rather than instantly. A couple of minutes of physical access and a can of aerosol w/a laptop and a few more tidbits and they were able to access everything that was left in the RAM.

Comment: So judging from your comments my files are safe from anybody been able to trace and view? and nothing is left on the network?

Comment: Is it the same if its a mounted mobile phone to a usb flash drive?